# Docker build says directory already exists but it is not

Tags: linux, docker, nginx

In dockerfile I am creating directory `/var/log/nginx` since it didn't exist in the container even though nginx.conf is set to save logs in /var/log/nginx

However, the docker build failed saying the directory /var/log/nginx already exists. But it doesn't.

Docker build error:

```
root@jsd-user-management:~/flask# docker build -t flask_app .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  716.8kB
Step 1/6 : FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.5
 ---> dea8fea96656
Step 2/6 : RUN mkdir  /var/log/nginx
 ---> Running in 9e9ff86747a7
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/nginx’: File exists
The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir  /var/log/nginx' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Inside Docker container:

```
root@jsd-user-management:~/flask# docker exec -it flask_jsd-user-management_1 bash
root@c6d43f610a51:/app/app# ls /var/log
root@c6d43f610a51:/app/app#
```

Surprisingly enough, when I attempt to create the directory from inside the container, it works. However, no logs are populated inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-p` flag.

> `-p, --parents`
> no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx
RUN ls /var/log/
```

It might be case parent director missing.

Comment: no, because the /var/log already exists in the container. Also nginx is installed and working so /var/log/nginx should already exist without me creating it.

Comment: how you run the cotainer? can you show the command?

Comment: I use docker-compose up and the webserver is operational

Comment: my question is, why nginx doesn't populate the logs inside /var/log/nginx even after it's created.

Comment: this somethign that depend on process, if Nginx is not started yet it will not populate the file, show the `CMD` of the dockerfile

Comment: `CMD [ "pipenv", "run","flask", "run"]` this is the CMD right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217601/discussion-between-adiii-and-omar-abdelrazik).